# Separating date and year, converting to datetime and creating a new column

Tags: python, datetime

Convert the date column to a datetime type.
Create a new column, issue_year, and set it to the year from date column.

I need to separate a date in the format 'Dec-11' into month and year. Dec being the month and 11 being the year.

I need to also create a new column for the year.

All data needs to be converted to datetime type.

I have tried:

```
loan_df.issue_d = pd.to_datetime(loan_df.issue_d, errors='coerce',format='%Y%m')
```

I am getting an NaT error when I run `loan_df.issue_d.head()`

But obviously I am missing something. Any suggestions all?

```
    print(loan_df['issue_d'].head())
    0    Dec-11
    1    Dec-11
    2    Dec-11
    3    Dec-11
    4    Dec-11
    Name: issue_d, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want keep the issue_date format:

```py
loan_df['issue_year'] = pd.to_datetime(loan_df['issue_date'], format='%b-%y').dt.year
print(loan_df)
```

---

```
  issue_date  issue_year
0     Dec-11        2011
1     Dec-11        2011
2     Dec-11        2011
3     Dec-11        2011
```

If you want to format issue_date :

```py
loan_df['issue_date'] = pd.to_datetime(loan_df['issue_date'], format='%b-%y')
loan_df['issue_year'] = loan_df['issue_date'].dt.year
print(loan_df)
```

---

```
  issue_date  issue_year
0 2011-12-01        2011
1 2011-12-01        2011
2 2011-12-01        2011
3 2011-12-01        2011
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `format="%b-%y"`:

```py
df['new_issue_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'], format='%b-%y')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  issue_d new_issue_d
0  Dec-11  2011-12-01
1  Jan-11  2011-01-01
2  Feb-13  2013-02-01
```

---

- **%b** (ex. *Sep*) - Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
- **%y** (ex. *11*) - Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: NaT error again.

Comment: @ric_m Maybe you have whitespaces around the dates? Try `df['issue_d'] = df['issue_d'].str.strip()` before the converting.

Comment: Okay, I stripped it. No change. I am getting a no attribute error for 'new_issue_d'

Comment: @ric_m Perhaps you're using different time locale. You can try to set locale to "C" (or "en_US") before converting: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')`

Comment: I was able to separate 'issue_d' and 'new_issue_d' - thank you. I am wondering how I can isolate the year and create a new column only reflecting the four digit year.

Comment: I was able to manage with '''loan_df['issue_year'] = loan_df['new_issue_d'].dt.year'''